# How to feed the weights of the neurons to the blobs in caffe and vice versa?

Tags: caffe, blobs

I am a very newbie to caffe.

I have a huge weight vector which contains the weights connecting the neurons of the neural network written in C++. I want to know use this weight vector as to define a neural network in Caffe and these weights will be the initial weights of the connecting neurons. How do I feed these weights into the Caffe blobs which is the fundamental way to hold parameter values like weights and biases in caffe.

After every iteration when the weights get updated, I also want to get their values from the blobs and put them back into this huge weight vector which I will access from the remaining part of code in C++.

Please tell me how to code this in caffe. It is actually a process of serialization and deserialization of the weights vector to and from blobs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can check the caffe.cpp file in the source code. It takes initial weights as an optional argument to initialize the layers. However, I am not sure if you can get the weights after each iteration in the format you need. But, it might give you some insights on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Can u let me know where do I feed a particular float value of the weight vector to any Blob. I mean which field of Blob will contain the weights and how to define that

Comment: I cannot help you with that, you might have to figure out yourself

Comment: I dont think there is any source named caffe.cpp. Which one did you mean

Comment: you can check [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/caffe.cpp)